# Daypilot - Load appointments from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, calendar, daypilot

I am creating a master rota using Daypilot.

I am currently storing appointments in the database but I would like to retrieve all appointments for a certain day and display them on a calendar, irrelevant of DATES.

E.G all appointments created on Monday should always be shown on a Monday, irrelevant of what the DATE is.

Current select

```
public DataTable GetAssignmentsForLocation(DayPilotCalendar calendar)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    var da = CreateDataAdapter("select * from [master_rota] where [LocationId] = @location and Week = @Week");

    AddParameterWithValue(da.SelectCommand, "location", (int)calendar.ClientState["location"]);
    AddParameterWithValue(da.SelectCommand, "week", (int)calendar.ClientState["week"]);

    da.Fill(dt);

    return dt;
}
```

And

```
 protected void DayPilotCalendar1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Command)
    {
        case "navigate":
            var start = (DateTime)e.Data["start"];
            DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = start;
            DayPilotCalendar1.DataSource = new DataManager_MasterRota().GetAssignmentsForLocation(DayPilotCalendar1);
            DayPilotCalendar1.DataBind();
            DayPilotCalendar1.Update();
            break;
        case "refresh":
            DayPilotCalendar1.DataSource = new DataManager_MasterRota().GetAssignmentsForLocation(DayPilotCalendar1);
            DayPilotCalendar1.DataBind();
            DayPilotCalendar1.Update();
            break;
        case "day":
            DayPilotCalendar1.ViewType = ViewTypeEnum.Day;
            DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate = (DateTime)e.Data["date"];

            DayPilotCalendar1.DataSource = new DataManager_MasterRota().GetAssignmentsForLocation(DayPilotCalendar1);
            DayPilotCalendar1.DataBind();
            DayPilotCalendar1.Update();
            break;
        case "week":
            DayPilotCalendar1.ViewType = ViewTypeEnum.Week;
            DayPilotCalendar1.DataSource = new DataManager_MasterRota().GetAssignmentsForLocation(DayPilotCalendar1);
            DayPilotCalendar1.DataBind();
            DayPilotCalendar1.Update();
            break;

    }
}
```

Creation

```
public void CreateAssignment(DateTime start, DateTime end, int location, int week, int person, string note, DayOfWeek day)
{
    using (DbConnection con = CreateConnection())
    {
        con.Open();

        // string id = "";
        var cmd = CreateCommand("insert into [master_rota] ([AssignmentStart], [AssignmentEnd], [LocationId], [PersonId], [AssignmentNote], week, day) values (@start, @end, @location, @person, @note, @Week, @day)", con);
        AddParameterWithValue(cmd, "start", start);
        AddParameterWithValue(cmd, "end", end);
        AddParameterWithValue(cmd, "location", location);
        AddParameterWithValue(cmd, "week", week);
        AddParameterWithValue(cmd, "person", person);
        AddParameterWithValue(cmd, "note", note);
        AddParameterWithValue(cmd, "day", day);

        cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Database entries: the database is recording the day for each entry, so in theory it should be possible to load all values for a given day value

E.G All entries for "Day 1", should all show on Monday, irrelevant of DATE

[image]

The calendar looks like the below. As you can see there are no dates shown, as it should always load the appointment if the DAY matches

[image]

Could someone please assist me in building the select statement so that the appointments load onto the calendar correctly? E.G Day 1 appointments to Monday, Day 2 to Tuesday etc....

Comment: You haven't shown us the code to populate the calendar? You're just filling a DataTable

Comment: added it in now

Comment: That's just the INSERT, what's the code you use to assign the data table to the Calendar?

Comment: Cool, last thing, what's the code in `GetAssignmentsForLocation`?

Comment: That's already posted, its the first bit of code at the top of the post

Comment: Doh, sorry! It's because the parameters in your SQL query need to be prefixed with @ as apomene answered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132924/discussion-between-david-hayward-and-jeremy-thompson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only data you are displaying is this weekly data (and the only view is the week view) then you can use the following approach:

When loading appointments, use the "Day" field to calculate a custom start and end dates and override the original values. It would be hard to do that in SQL but you can modify GetAssignmentsForLocation() to post-process the data set easily:

```
public DataTable GetAssignmentsForLocation(DayPilotCalendar calendar)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    var da = CreateDataAdapter("select * from [master_rota] where [LocationId] = @location and Week = @Week");

    AddParameterWithValue(da.SelectCommand, "@location", (int)calendar.ClientState["location"]);
    AddParameterWithValue(da.SelectCommand, "@week", (int)calendar.ClientState["week"]);

    da.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
       int dayOfWeek = (int) dr["Day"];
       DateTime start = (DateTime) dr["AssignmentStart"];
       DateTime end = (DateTime) dr["AssignmentEnd"];

       TimeSpan duration = end - start;
       TimeSpan startTime = start.TimeOfDay;

       dr["AssignmentStart"] = calendar.VisibleStart.AddDays(dayOfWeek).AddTime(startTime);
       dr["AssignmentEnd"] = calendar.VisibleStart.AddDays(dayOfWeek).AddTime(startTime).AddTime(duration);

    }

    return dt;
}
```

Note that this only works for Sunday as the first day of week (i.e. calendar.VisibleStart is always Sunday).

Comment: Amazing, this works.  Thanks so much, you have no idea how much this will help our organisation.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `@`  inside your parameters binding:

```
 AddParameterWithValue(da.SelectCommand, "@location", (int)calendar.ClientState["location"]);
 AddParameterWithValue(da.SelectCommand, "@week", (int)calendar.ClientState["week"]);
```

Comment: Good pickup, I'd also add using a spoc will be much more efficient with indexes on location and week

Comment: Hi, thanks, this helped with that part, but it doesnt solve my original problem that i requested

Answer (score 1):

Also, I modified the create, so that it can work by having Saturday as the starting day, so it doesn't need to have to start on a sunday.  Obviously you can change it so that any day could be the "starting day"

```
 public void CreateAssignment(DateTime start, DateTime end, int location, int week, int person, string note, DayOfWeek day)
    {
        using (DbConnection con = CreateConnection())
        {
            con.Open();
            //string id = "";

            var cmd = CreateCommand("insert into [master_rota] ([AssignmentStart], [AssignmentEnd], [LocationId], [PersonId], [AssignmentNote], week, day) values (@start, @end, @location, @person, @note, @Week, @day)", con);
            AddParameterWithValue(cmd, "start", start);
            AddParameterWithValue(cmd, "end", end);
            AddParameterWithValue(cmd, "location", location);
            AddParameterWithValue(cmd, "week", week);
            AddParameterWithValue(cmd, "person", person);
            AddParameterWithValue(cmd, "note", note);
            if (day == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            {
                AddParameterWithValue(cmd, "day", day - 6);
            }
            else
            AddParameterWithValue(cmd, "day", day + 1);

            cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        }
    }
```